# non-degenerate basic feasible of Polyhydron

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I couldn't show this problem. Can somebody help me by this question?

Consider a polyhedron  $\{X \in \mathbb{R}^n | AX \leq b, X \geq 0 \}$ and a non-degenerate basic feasible solution $X^*$. We introduce slack variables z and construct a corresponding polyhedron  $\{(X,Z)| Ax + Z = b, X\geq 0, Z \geq 0\}$ in standard form. Show that $(X^*,  b – AX^*)$ is a non-degenerate basic feasible solution for the new polyhedron.